# div wipe/reveal without affecting content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've run into a bit of trouble with a project.

I have a menu item, when it is clicked I would like a loading animation that will wipe left-to-right and change the colour of both the text and the background.

The best way I could think to do this is to duplicate the div, apply a 'cloned' class that changes the colours and lays it atop the clicked div. I can't seem to make a wipe work though.

I'm trying to use clip:

```
$('.flight').click(function () {
    $(this).clone(true).addClass('cloned').appendTo($(this).parent())
    $(this).siblings('.cloned').stop().animate({
        'clip': 'rect(0px 0px 300px 0px)'
    }, 1000)
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7y12y8z5/)

Any advice on where I'm going wrong would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a work-around from the clip issue. It's not pretty but it works! I'm only allowing myself to use this as the animation is not required for functionality, and the cloned block is to be deleted upon completion.

```
$('.flight').click(function() {
  // Clone and add the class
  $(this).clone(true).addClass('cloned').appendTo($(this).parent())
  // For every div under .cloned fix the width and height, this will prevent
  // any responsiveness that we don't want.
  jQuery.each($('.cloned div'), function(){
    $(this).css('width', $(this).innerWidth())
    $(this).css('max-height', $(this).innerHeight())
  })
  // Set the container width to 0 now, would not work before as we need
  // calculable widths. Then animate!
  $('.cloned').css('width', '0')
  $('.cloned').animate({
    width: '100%'
  })
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7y12y8z5/5/)